# trying to reshape a numpy array to from 4X4 to 2X2

Tags: numpy

I have a simple numpy array of `('left_lines =', (4, 4))` which is `[x1,y1,x2,y2]` which is `4x4` and trying to reshape it to `2x2` and take the mean for X's and Y's . I use this code:

```
mean_left = np.mean(left_lines.reshape(2,2),axis=0)
```

But I get this error:

> total size of new array must be unchanged

```
print(type(left_lines))
```

Gives:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Not sure what is wrong with reshape syntax !?

Comment: What's `left_lines.dtype`?

Comment: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: `left_lines.reshape(2,2)` - you're trying to put 16 numbers into 4 cells there.

Comment: so I should change this to 8X2. Thanks that worked